# merging varying number of rows by multiple conditions in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, validation, merge, pandas-groupby

**Problem**: merging varying number of rows by multiple conditions

Here is a stylistic example of how the dataset looks like

```
"index" "connector" "type" "q_text" "a_text" "varx" ...
   1        1111      1      aa       NA       xx
   2        9999      2      NA       tt       NA
   3        1111      2      NA       uu       NA
   4        9999      1      bb       NA       yy
   5        9999      1      cc       NA       zz
```

**Goal**: how the dataset **should** look like

```
"index" "connector" "type" "type.1" "q_text" "q_text.1" "a_text" "a_text.1 " "varx" "varx.1" ...
   1        1111      1       2        aa        NA        NA        uu        xx      NA
   2        9999      1       2        bb        NA        NA        tt        yy      NA
   3        9999      1       2        cc        NA        NA        tt        zz      NA
```

**Logic**: Column "type" has either value 1 or 2 while multiple rows have value 1 but only one row (with the same value in "connector") has value 2

**If**
same values in "connector"
**then**
**merge**
rows of "type"=2  with rows of "type"=1
**but**
(because multiple rows of "type"=1 have the same value in "connector")
**duplicate**
the corresponding rows of type=2
and
**merge**
all of the other rows that also have the same value in "connector" and are of "type"=1

**My results**: Not all are merged because multiple rows of "type"=1 are associated with UNIQUE rows of "type"=2

Most similar questions are answered using SQL, which i cannot use here.

```
df2 = df.copy()
df.index.astype(str)
df2.index.astype(str)
pd.merge(df,df2, how='left', on='connector',right_index=True, left_index=True)
df3 = pd.merge(df.set_index('connector'),df2.set_index('connector'), right_index=True, left_index=True).reset_index()
dfNew = df.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['connector'], right_on = ['connector'])
```

Can i achieve my goal by goupby() ?

Solution by @victor__von__doom

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = df.groupby('connector', sort=True).apply(lambda c: list(zip(*c.values[:,2:].tolist()))).reset_index(name='merged')
    df[['here', 'are', 'all', 'columns', 'except', 'for', 'the', 'connector', 'column']]  = pd.DataFrame(df.merged.tolist())
    df = df.drop(['merged'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it is really messy to just keep concatenating new columns onto your original `DataFrame` when rows are merged, especially when the number of columns is very large. Furthermore, if you end up merging 3 rows for 1 connector value and 4 rows for another (for example), the only way to include all values is to make empty columns for some rows, which is never a good idea. Instead, I've made it so that the merged rows get combined into tuples, which can then be parsed efficiently while keeping the size of your `DataFrame` manageable:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1111,9999,1111,9999,9999],
                     [1,2,2,1,1], ['aa', 'NA', 'NA', 'bb', 'cc'],
                     ['NA', 'tt', 'uu', 'NA', 'NA'],
                     ['xx', 'NA', 'NA', 'yy', 'zz']])

    df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns = ["index", "connector",
                          "type", "q_text", "a_text", "varx"])

    df = df.groupby("connector", sort=True).apply(lambda c: list(zip(*c.values[:,2:].tolist()))).reset_index(name='merged')
    df[["type", "q_text", "a_text", "varx"]]  = pd.DataFrame(df.merged.tolist())
    df = df.drop(['merged'], axis=1)
```

The final `DataFrame` looks like:

```
  connector       type        q_text        a_text          varx ...
0      1111     (1, 2)      (aa, NA)      (NA, uu)      (xx, NA) ...
1      9999  (2, 1, 1)  (NA, bb, cc)  (tt, NA, NA)  (NA, yy, zz) ...
```

Which is much more compact and readable.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very useful and a better way to do it. I get the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` and added the code that i adapted from yours at the end of the question

Comment: Weird - the code I posted runs perfectly on my system. Can you identify what exactly is causing the error? If not, can you post the code that you adapted? It's possible you missed something.

Comment: Okay, when you write "all columns but the connector column", does that include the "index" column? Is that an actual column you created, or the default pandas index column? If that's the default pandas one (*not* one you created), then you need to change ```zip(*c.values[:,2:]...``` to ```zip(*c.values[:,1:]...```. Either way, it sounds like the error is coming from the line where I did ```pd.DataFrame(df.merged.tolist())``` - it's unpacking the wrong number of columns, somehow.

Comment: the code is at the end of the question above. Maybe because i didnt include the "index" column in the code? i have a natural index but not a separate "index" column and your code says something like `[:,2:]` while i dont actually leave those two out but only the "connector" column as i tried to highlight in the code at the end of the question. Ill try `[:,1:]` then

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. I included an explicit index column, so I sliced from the second (index + connector) column, but with your setup you should just slice from the first column (connector). If you change it to ```[:,1:]```, it should work perfectly.