# merging varying number of rows and columns by multiple conditions in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, merge, left-join

**updated Problem:** Why does it not merge `a_date`, `a_par`, `a_cons`, `a_ment` and `a_le`. These are appended as columns without values but in the original dataset they have values.

Here is how the dataset looks like

```
         connector   type   q_text   a_text   var1   var2 
   1        1111      1      aa       None    xx     ps
   2        9999      2      None     tt      jjjj   pppp
   3        1111      2      None     uu      None   oo
   4        9999      1      bb       None    yy     Rt
   5        9999      1      cc       None    zz     tR
```

**Goal**: how the dataset **should** look like

```
         connector   q_text   a_text    var1   var1.1   var2   var2.1
   1        1111      aa        uu       xx     None     ps      oo
   2        9999      bb        tt       yy     jjjj     Rt      pppp
   3        9999      cc        tt       zz     jjjj     tR      pppp
```

**Logic**: Column `type` has either value `1` or `2` with multiple rows having value `1` but only one row (with the same value in `connector`) has value `2`

Here are the main merging **rules:**

1. Merge every row of `type=1` with its corresponding (`connector`) `type=2` row.
2. Since multiple rows of `type=1` have the same `connector` value, I don't want to merge solely one row of `type=1` but all of them, each with the sole `type==2` row.
3. Since some columns (e.g. `a_text`) follow left-join logic, values can be overridden without adding an extra column.
4. Since `var2` values cannot be merged by left-join because they are non-exclusionary with regard to the rows connector value, i want to have extra columns (`var1.1`, `var2.1`) for those values (`pppp`, `jjjj`).

In summary (and having in mind that i only speak of rows that have the same connector values): If `q_text` is `None` i first, want to replace the values in `a_text` with the `a_text` value (see above table `tt` and `uu`) of the corresponding row (same connector value) and secondly, want to append some other values (`var1` and `var2`) of the very same corresponding row as new columns.
Also, there are rows with a unique `connector` value that is not going to be matched. I want to keep those rows though.

I only want to "drop" the `type=2` rows that get merged with their corresponding `type=1` row**(s)**. In other words: I dont want to keep the rows of type=2 that have a match and get merged into their corresponding (connector) `type=1` rows. I want to keep all other rows though.

Solution by @victor__von__doom here
[merging varying number of rows by multiple conditions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617140/merging-varying-number-of-rows-by-multiple-conditions-in-python)
was answered when i originally wanted to keep all of the `"type"=2` columns(values).

**Code i used**: merged `Perso`, `q_text` and `a_text`

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'a_date'] = df['q_date']
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'a_par'] = df['par']
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'a_cons'] = df['cons']
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'a_ment'] = df['pret']
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'a_le'] = df['q_le']
my_cols = ['Perso', 'q_text','a_text', 'a_le', 'q_le', 'q_date', 'par', 'cons', 'pret', 'q_le', 'a_date','a_par', 'a_cons', 'a_ment', 'a_le']
df[my_cols] = df.sort_values(['connector','type']).groupby('connector')[my_cols].transform(lambda x: x.bfill())
df.dropna(subset=['a_text', 'Perso'],inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

**Data**: This is a representation of the core dataset. Unfortunately i cannot share the actual data due to privacy laws.

| Perso | ID | per | q_le | a_le | pret | par | form | q_date | name | IO_ID | part | area | q_text | a_text | country | cons | dig | connector | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J Ws | 1-1/4/2001-11-12/1 | 1999-2009 | None | 4325 | 'Mi, h', 'd' | Cew | Thre | 2001-11-12 | None | 345 | rede | s — H | None | wr ede | Terd e | e r | 2001-11-12.1.g9 | 999999999 | 2 |
| S ts | 9-3/6/2003-10-14/1 | 1994-2004 | None | 23 | 'sd, h' | d-g | Thre | 2003-10-14 | None | 34555 | The | l? I | None | Tre | Thr ede | re | 2001-04-16.1.a9 | 333333333 | 2 |
| On d | 6-1/6/2005-09-03/1 | 1992-2006 | None | 434 | 'uu h' | d-g | Thre | 2005-09-03 | None | 7313 | Thde | l? I | None | T e | Th rede | dre | 2001-08-07.1.e4 | 111111111 | 2 |
| None | 3-4/4/2000-07-07/1 | 1992-2006 | 1223 | None | 'uu h' | dfs | Thre | 2000-07-07 | Th r | 7413 | Thde | Tddde | Thd de | None | Thre de |  | 2001-07-06.1.j3 | 111111111 | 1 |
| None | 2-1/6/2001-11-12/1 | 1999-2009 | 1444 | None | 'Mi, h', 'd' | d-g | Thre | 2001-11-12 | T rj | 7431 | Thde | l? I | Th dde | None | Thr ede |  | 2001-11-12.1.s7 | 999999999 | 1 |
| None | 1-6/4/2007-11-01/1 | 1993-2010 | 2353 | None | None | d-g | Thre | 2007-11-01 | Thrj | 444 | Thed | l. I | Tgg gg | None | Thre de | we e | 2001-06-11.1.g9 | 654982984 | 1 |

Comment: if `a_text` has a value for `type == 1`, what should be done?

Comment: `a_text` only has `None` for type=1 that is why `None` values in `a_text` shall be overridden by the corresponding `type=2` values (`tt`, `uu`)

Comment: In summary, if `q_text` is 'np.nan' or 'none' or string 'NA', you want to replace the values in `a_text` == 1 with the values in `a_text` == 2? Additionally, you want var1.1 and var 2.1 to be created with values from `a_text` == 2?

Comment: In summary (and having in mind that i only speak of rows that have the **same** `connector` values): If `q_text` is `None` i first, want to replace the values in `a_text` with the `a_text` value (see above table `tt` and `uu`) of the corresponding **row** (same `connector` value) and secondly, want to append some other values (`var1` and `var2`) of the very same corresponding **row** as new columns. Sorry for the difficulties but i am not a native speaker and have a hard time expressing my intent. Thanks for reading though :)

Comment: See if my new answer addresses all the variations of your question

Comment: i added the code i used and its output above. Unfortunately 0 rows were returned

Comment: Every version has new discoveries. Can you share all the columns please. I will try and give you a solution thats independent of how many columns you have and focuses on updates to only the key columns

Comment: i reran the code by adding more columns. There is no change to my code. It works even if there are other columns. It does not modify the values for those columns. Can you please share examples of rows where the value is modified please?

Comment: i promise these are all the columns. My apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: Try the changes. Also share some sample data so I can check and fix the gaps.

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` already saved my day :) thanks. I will get back here in approx. 1 hour that is the time it takes to load the dataset. I will share two example rows above

Comment: btw, to dropna multiple columns, you can give `subset=['q_text', 'person']`

Comment: again, it returned an empty dataframe. This time 37 empty columns.
btw, there are not always matching rows. Some rows dont have similar `connector` values if thats the problem..

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that there could be a connector row with type == 1 without a type == 2 OR you could have a connector row with type == 2 without a type == 1 ?

Comment: Yes, both is true for this dataset. Some if not most of these rows do not have a matching connector value in other rows. In other words, not all of `type=1` rows` connector values are the same for other rows. I want to keep the rows that do not have a match though. I rephrased it above "My approach". Sorry for the bit by bit information. i never thought this would be important

Comment: If you want to keep the records with type=2, then comment out these two lines .... `df.dropna(subset=['q_text'],inplace=True)` and `df.dropna(subset=['Person'],inplace=True)`

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can share a link to the raw data so I can look at it. Or provide a sample set of rows so I can play with it and fix any issues. For now, I am unable to see a reason for these records to get deleted. My edit v2 shows clearly that the records stay on and updates as requested.

Comment: you can do df.head(20) and put them on google drive or some common location for me to review. Even a screenshot will do

Comment: i moved `Perso` into `my_cols` and it worked somewhat. So far, merging of `Perso`, `q_text` and `a_text` worked. `a_date`, `a_par`, `a_cons`, `a_ment` and `a_le` did not work, these are empty

Comment: Did this get solved? Do you need any additional help? If yes, I can work on it. If not, we can wrap this up

Comment: Hey Joe thanks for your help. I would need additional help but i am too busy atm. That is why i declare this as solved but return next week for a more precise adaptation of this question. Again, most of what i wanted is working, so for the moment thanks.

Comment: Awesome. When you have time, post the new question and I will be happy to support you. If needed I can help set a bounty for your question as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT v2 with additional columns

This version ensures the values in the additional columns are not impacted.

```
c = ['connector','type','q_text','a_text','var1','var2','cumsum','country','others']
d = [[1111, 1, 'aa',  None, 'xx',   'ps',   0, 'US', 'other values'],
     [9999, 2, None,  'tt', 'jjjj', 'pppp', 0, 'UK', 'no values'],
     [1111, 2, None,  'uu', None,   'oo',   1, 'US', 'some values'],
     [9999, 1, 'bb',  None, 'yy',   'Rt',   1, 'UK', 'more values'],
     [9999, 1, 'cc',  None, 'zz',   'tR',   2, 'UK', 'less values']]

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

print (df)

df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'var1.1'] = df['var1']
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'var2.1'] = df['var2']

my_cols = ['q_text','a_text','var1','var2','var1.1','var2.1']

df[my_cols] = df.sort_values(['connector','type']).groupby('connector')[my_cols].transform(lambda x: x.bfill())

df.dropna(subset=['q_text'],inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

print (df)
```

Original DataFrame:

```
   connector  type q_text a_text  var1  var2  cumsum country        others
0       1111     1     aa   None    xx    ps       0      US  other values
1       9999     2   None     tt  jjjj  pppp       0      UK     no values
2       1111     2   None     uu  None    oo       1      US   some values
3       9999     1     bb   None    yy    Rt       1      UK   more values
4       9999     1     cc   None    zz    tR       2      UK   less values
```

Updated DataFrame

```
   connector  type q_text a_text var1 var2  cumsum country        others  var1.1 var2.1
0       1111     1     aa     uu   xx   ps       0      US  other values    None     oo 
1       9999     1     bb     tt   yy   Rt       1      UK   more values    jjjj   pppp 
2       9999     1     cc     tt   zz   tR       2      UK   less values    jjjj   pppp
```

Comment: Is 'NA' a string? I did find a problem. If we did not have `2 1111 2 NaN uu NaN`, then the value from '2222' gets updated for `1111`. Fixing it now

Comment: Is your data `NA` string? If so, I need to change the code. It will work only if it is `NaN` or `None`

Comment: Ok. Let me change the code as the value is string 'NA'

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Do you need additional help? I assume with the df.loc assignment and sort_values, you should be good to go

Comment: It doesent work as intended. As far as i was able to retrace, the `q_text` values get overriden by `NA`s. I could not identify any merged rows in the output. Your tuple solution works though. I added the code i adapted from you at the end of above question.

Comment: i changed it from NA string to type= None

Comment: btw, you don't have to have the `"` before and after each variable name. Looks like your column names were setup as `'"a_text"'` which would then result in `"a_text"` as your column name.

Comment: prior edits don't need to be in the answer - just post your updated solution.