# iteratively merging varying number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, iteration

earlier discussion with help of @Joe Ferndz here:
[merging varying number of rows and columns by multiple conditions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629337/merging-varying-number-of-rows-and-columns-by-multiple-conditions-in-python)

how the dataset looks like

```
         connector   type   q_text     a_text     var1
   1        1111      1      aaaa       None      xxxx  
   2        9999      2      None       tttt      jjjj
   3        1111      2      None       uuuu      None
   4        9999      1      bbbb       None      yyyy  
   5        9999      1      cccc       None      zzzz
```

**Logic** merge every row with `type = 1` to its corresponding (same value in `connector`) `type = 2`. Code that does this:

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 2, 'var1.1'] = df['var1']
my_cols = ['q_text','a_text','var1']
df[my_cols] = df.sort_values(['connector','type']).groupby('connector')[my_cols].transform(lambda x: x.bfill())
df.dropna(subset=['q_text'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

how the dataset then looks like

```
         connector   q_text      a_text      var1    var1.1
   1        1111      aaaa        uuuu       xxxx     None 
   2        9999      bbbb        tttt       yyyy     jjjj  
   3        9999      cccc        None       zzzz     zzzz
```

**Problem** with multiple rows having `type = 1` but only one row  having `type = 2` (same `connector` value). therefore i need to merge `type = 2` row eventually multiple times.

**Question** Why does it merge only one row?

how the dataset **should** look like (compare row 3 values and you will see what i mean)

```
         connector   q_text      a_text      var1    var1.1
   1        1111      aaaa        uuuu       xxxx     None 
   2        9999      bbbb        tttt       yyyy     jjjj  
   3        9999      cccc        tttt       zzzz     jjjj
```

`a_text` follows left-join logic, values can be overridden without adding an extra column. Contrary, `var1` values are non-exclusionary with regard to the rows connector value, that is why i want to have extra column (`var1.1`) for those values (`jjjj`). There are rows with a unique `connector` value that will never be merged, but I want to keep those.

Comment: Copying your sample dataset, and then running your code/logic doesn't produce the dataset as you showed above in (`how the dataset then looks like` part)

Comment: Also is `q_text` always None for type 2, and `a_text`  always None for type 1 rows?

Comment: Yes, `q_text` is always None for `type = 2` rows and `a_text` always None for `type = 1` rows. I accidentally `subset=['a_text']` instead of `q_text` and edited it now.

Comment: Ok not sure of your logic, but what you want can be done using merge operation in pandas. Posted an answer to show you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to merge rows with `type = 1` to rows having `type = 2`, but in the code/logic you showed doesn't involve use of [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method, which will actually do what you desire.

First segregate the rows with `type = 1` and `type = 2` into 2 different dataframes **df1** and **df2**. Then simply merge these 2 dataframes on **connector** values. It will automatically map multiple rows having `type = 1` in **df1** with only one row having `type = 2` in **df2** (with same connector values). Also since you want to keep rows with a unique connector value that will never be merged, use **`how='outer'`** param to perform an outer **merge** and keep all values.

After merge, select what all columns you finally want and rename them accordingly:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.type == 1].copy()
df2 = df.loc[df.type == 2].copy()
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='connector', how='outer')
merged_df = merged_df.loc[:,['connector','q_text_x','a_text_y','var1_x','var1_y']]
merged_df.rename(columns={'q_text_x':'q_text','a_text_y':'a_text','var1_x':'var1','var1_y':'var1.1'}, inplace=True)


>>> merged_df
   connector q_text a_text  var1 var1.1
0       1111   aaaa   uuuu  xxxx   None
1       9999   bbbb   tttt  yyyy   jjjj
2       9999   cccc   tttt  zzzz   jjjj
```